# Why isn't my Perl program reaping children processes after fork?

Tags: perl, ipc, fork, zombie-process

I have been trying to write a bare-bones ping scanner using Perl for internal use. Since it scans a 24-bit CIDR network the script takes too long to run if it runs in a single thread. I have tried adding fork functionality to speed up the process but my [first attempt](http://pastebin.com/fc457b0b) was taking pretty much the same time since there was only one child process active at any given time.

I read up on child processes in the [perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html) document and also in the [Perl Cookbook](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596003135/) and came up with the second version:

```
##Install the CHLD SIG handler
$SIG{CHLD} = \&REAPER;
sub REAPER {
    my $childPID;
    while (( $childPID = waitpid(-1, WNOHANG)) > 0) {
        print "$childPID exited\n";
    }
    $SIG{CHLD} = \&REAPER;
}

my $kidpid;
for (1 .. 254) {
    my $currIP = join ".", (@ipSubset[0,1,2], $_);

    die "Could not fork()\n" unless defined ($kidpid = fork);
    if ($kidpid) {
        #Parent process
        #Does nothing
    } 
    else {
        #Child process
        my $pingConn = Net::Ping->new();    #TCP
        say "$currIP up" if $pingConn->ping($currIP);
        $pingConn->close(); 

        #Nothing else to do
        exit;
    }
}

say "Finished scanning $ipRange/24";
```

When I scan my internal network the output is:

```
$perl pingrng2.pl 192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2 up
5380 exited
192.168.1.102 up
192.168.1.100 up
5478 exited
5480 exited
Finished scanning 192.168.1.1/24
```

As can be seen in the result, the threads which do a successful scan print the "up" message, exit cleanly and are reaped by the parent process. The other 251 threads meanwhile are left dangling attached to '/sbin/init' as can be seen by a quick 'ps -ef' listing. If I add a 'print "Child: $currIP ending\n"' in the child processing block just before the exit statement I get the output from the remaining 251 processes on my terminal "after" my perl script has exited.

What's going on here? I thought that the $SIG{CHLD} subroutine coupled with the waitpid loop would reap all the child processes and ensure that no zombies/dangling processes were left in the system.

In the same breath I would also like to be able to run a specific number of child processes at any given time, say for example, 'n' children running concurrently, whenever one exits the parent process starts another child if needed but has no more than 'n' children at any given moment. Is this possible? If yes could I get some pseudo-code to help guide me?

Comment: Any reason why your loop goes from 1-254(253?) instead of 0-255?

Comment: Matt Boehm 255 is commonly the broadcast address (assuming a /24 subnet).  0 also has a special meaning (in a /24), but I forget what it is.

Comment: Matt, all 0's is reserved for the network ID and all 1's for the broadcast address.

Comment: In a CIDR net, there are two reserved addresses, the one with the local part all zeros (for /24, x.y.z.0) which is the address of the network itself, and the one with the local part all ones (for /24, x.y.z.255) which is the broadcast adress

Comment: Maybe you should try NMap instead.

Comment: nmap is overkill for what I am trying to do here, and I cant use it at work so the Perl script is the easiest way to things done.

Comment: Those processes attached to 'init' would be reaped by 'init' when they finish work.  They got reparented to 'init' because parent process finished before them (no `wait` or `waitpid`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like your parent process is finishing before the children (and therefore never getting a chance to reap them).  Try this instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Net::Ping;

my @ipSubset = (192, 168, 10);

my $i = 0;
my @pids;
for my $octet (1 .. 254) {
    my $currIP = join ".", @ipSubset[0 .. 2], $octet;

    die "Could not fork()\n" unless defined (my $pid = fork);

    #parent saves chlidren's pids and loops again
    if ($pid) {
        push @pids, $pid;
        next;
    } 

    #child process
    my $pingConn = Net::Ping->new;
    say "$currIP up" if $pingConn->ping($currIP);
    $pingConn->close(); 
    exit;
}

#wait on the children
for my $pid (@pids) {
    waitpid $pid, 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried setting it to 'IGNORE' but the majority of the threads are still left dangling as explained above.

Comment: I've been looking all over for an easy way to do this...that little for loop at the end was all I needed...many thanks

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [Parallel::ForkManager](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Parallel::ForkManager). It takes care of all those little details for you.

Answer (score 3):

When a thread calls ping() it keeps trying to ping the IP until it sets a response.  to fix this, try to include a timeout as a second argument in ping().  It looks like right now, those remaining threads are continuing to ping for a response until they get one.

As far as having a set N number of threads, why not break the 0-255 into chunks, for instance having two threads, one that goes from 0-127 and one that goes 128-255?  I would use some multiple of 2 for your number of threads for simplicity's sake.